# 6 transfer functions result to out of gas

Tags: solidity, address.transfer

I have a function that in first call just counts values and in next calls transfer some amount of ETH. It's like:

```
function() public {
  ...
  if (val !=0) {
    address1.transfer(val.mul(part1).div(100));
    address2.transfer(val.mul(part2).div(100));
    address3.transfer(val.mul(part3).div(100));
    address4.transfer(val.mul(part4).div(100));
    address5.transfer(val.mul(part5).div(100));
    address6.transfer(val.mul(part6).div(100));
  }
 val = msg.value;
}
```

The first call requires 368,351 of gas and the second call cannot be sent because of

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). 
The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending? 
gas required exceeds allowance (7007659) or always failing transaction
```

If I delete 5 transfers then it works. As I know transfer requires only 2100 of gas so I have a question: is it possible that 6 transfers increase gas requiements so high or I have a mistake anywhere in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transfer may fail because there is not enough ether on sender contract's balance, or because recipient is a smart contract that does not accept payments, or needs more than 2300 gas in order to process incoming ether transfers.

Assuming that `part1 + part2 + ... + part6 ≤ 100` I would guess, that at least one of your destination addresses is a smart contract and there are some problems with it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Every out of 6 addresses is a smart-contract with a payable fallback function. Sender's contract has to have enough ether too...

Comment: OK, then we have only one option left: one of these fallback functions needs more than 2300 gas.

Comment: Ah, yes. There was a stupid mistake. One of smart-contracts was looping this transaction.